# 3D Box Collision in Unity game not working despite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, physics, game-development

So in my game development I am making a tennis game, I have tried to develop a box collision between the player and the tennis ball but it doesn't work, I added the Rigidbody component and ticked the isTrigger box and when I did tick the isTrigger box on both the player and the Tennis bat the collision triggers but only when I press the keys before the game runs. However, When I untick the isTrigger box on the player and the Tennis bat it does not trigger whatsoever no matter what. Here is my code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Leftmove left;
    float speed = 3f;
    float force = 10;
    bool hit;
    public Transform target;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 position = transform.position;
        Vector3 positiont = target.position;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            hit = true;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.F))
        {
            hit = false;
        }

        if ((hit == true) && (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)))
        {
            positiont.x += speed * Time.deltaTime;

        }

        if ((hit == true) && (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)))
        {
            positiont.x -= speed * Time.deltaTime;

        }

        if ((hit == true) && (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)))
        {
            positiont.z -= speed * Time.deltaTime;

        }

        if ((hit == true) && (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)))
        {
            positiont.z += speed * Time.deltaTime;

        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && hit == false)
        {

            position.x += speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) && hit == false)
        {
            position.x -= speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && hit == false)
        {
            position.z -= speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) && hit == false)
        {
            position.z += speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        transform.position = position;
        target.position = positiont;


       
      
    }

    private void CollisionTrigger(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Tennis ball"))
        {
            Vector3 dir = target.position - transform.position;
            other.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = dir.normalized * force;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: What is the method CollisionTrigger supposed to be for? Have you read the names of methods for triggers and collisions? This will be why its not working

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be lacking the basic knowledge of how collision works in Unity. For collision detection to work you need the following

1. One non-kinematic Rigidbody
2. Collisders attached to both the colliding gameobjects.

The function OnCollisionEnter is called if the colliders are not triggers. In case of trigger OnTriggerEnter is called. You read this article on [basics of Unity Colliders](https://vionixstudio.com/2019/09/04/unity-collider-explained/) to know more.